# RESTful API: What's the best path specification for bulk write operation?

Tags: rest, api-design

Imagine that we are designing API layers around a data object called `person`

I know that in RESTful API:

a "create person" call should have path be like:
`PUT https://server-host/persons/<person_id>`
a "update person" call should have path be like:
`UPDATE https://server-host/persons/<person_id>`

What if I wanted to do bulk operation i.e. not create/update one person, but create/update multiple person, maybe with a list of ids?

I know that for batch read operation, `GET https://server-host/persons` is the replacement to `GET https://server-host/persons/<person_id>`.

But this gets all the persons, except maybe has pagination that is built into its backend so each call only returns some of them. There's also no good suggestion over what the path should be if one would like to provide a list of ids.